# Failed to read the 'status' property from 'XMLHttpRequest': the object's state must not be OPENED

Tags: javascript

I try to detect rather the page status is 404 or not by this code :

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();  
    request.open('GET', 'http://xxxxxxxx.me/yossi/default.aspx', true);  
    request.send();  

    if (request.status === "404") {  
        alert("Oh no, it does not exist!");
    }
```

and I get this strangiest error in my browser console :

> Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to read the 'status' property from 'XMLHttpRequest': the object's state must not be OPENED.

any clue whats going on ?

Comment: Can you wait for a `readystatechanged`? ie. add an `onreadstatechanged` listener.

Comment: it's onreadystatechange event handler and NOT onreadystatechanged ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're opening the connection as ASYNC `request.open('GET', 'http://*****/yossi/default.aspx', true);` (the `true` part of the request).

This means that the `request.send();` call is made and *immediately* continues execution of your program. While your program is continuing to process the next lines of code, the XMLHttpRequest is doing its own work in the background and making the HTTP request and thus the connection is currently in an "Open" state when the following code is hit:

```
if (request.status === "404") {  
  alert("Oh no, it does not exist!");
}
```

#### You have two options

1. Make the `request.send();` call synchronous (vs async). This is **NOT RECOMMENDED** as the browser's UI will freeze while the call is being made until your request returns.
2. You need to add a callback for when the requests' `state` has changed. This is done with an `onreadystatechange` property off of your `request` variable. Within the callback, you can check the status because it is not until the request has been completed that you would even be able to know if the status was "404" or not (or any other status for that matter). An example taken from http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_onreadystatechange.asp

Example of async call with `onreadystatechange` callback:

```
request.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (request.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==404) {
    alert("Oh no, it does not exist!");
  }
}
```

Comment: callback like that ?   :     xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {...}

Comment: Yes, I have added some additional code to my answer that outlines this better with an actual example. You'll want to read up more on this and XMLHttpRequest further however to better understand the ready states that exist and how to use them.

Comment: I agree with @MaKR below, that you should look into a library like jQuery as it handles this very well http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Cant use Jquery in this case, so I try to handle it with JS.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Make your if block like this:

```
if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status === 404) { ... }
```

You're not waiting until the page finishes loading.  You're using an asynchronous request, but the way you are handling it makes it synchronous.  If I were you I'd look up asynchronous AJAX or try using JQuery.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

Comment: If I try your suggestion, it does eliminate the error, but it does not detecting the 404 status..  by any chance it is becuase the readyState ?

Comment: I haven't coded AJAX without JQuery in about 6 months, but are you sure readystate is a string?  The doc I linked to specifies that its data type is short, I'll edit answer so it doesn't specify string like it did previously.